# Display/Hide node page as modal with drupal_goto or similar way

Tags: 7

I want to display a node page I built inside a modal or overlay and be able to open/close the modal with simple commands.

That is without the need of an html element like clicking a link like I've seen in some examples just using something like: drupal_gotto($url. ?open/?close) so that I could call it inside a rule.

Also I might need to open a modal on top of another modalpage.

Answer (score 0):

I did it with Overlay Paths module but it was not working as I expected, I had to do these things:

1. drupal_goto(current_path(), array('fragment' => 'overlay=path-alias'));
2. Non-admin overlay paths: *path-alias

[check here for more](https://www.drupal.org/project/overlay_paths/issues/2948378)